# How to check if an array field matches an array query mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have an issue fetching data from a MongoDB database that contains an array and also retrieve elements that are not in the query array.

The database is structured like below:

```
{
   "name": "James",
   "visitedPlaces": ['Germany', "Scotland"]
},
{
   "name": "John",
   "visitedPlaces": ['India', "Russia"]
}
```

I want to query the VisitedPlaces to return only return people that have *not* visited Russia and India.

NOTE: I am querying the database with another array.

```
 db.Profile.find(
    { VisitedPlaces: { $elemMatch: { $nin: ["India", "Russia"] } } }
 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use $all to query an array that contains both the another array:

```
    db.Profile.find(
            { visitedPlaces: {$not:{$all:["India", "Russia"]}}}
    )
```